# Choose a Valid JDK Directory

Tags: android-studio

My question is about an error in Android Studio.

I'm getting a JDK error whenever i try to build my app because Android Studio is struggling ti find where the JDK is installed.

How can i fix this error? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> for Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for Windows/Linux to pull up the Project Structure dialog. In there, you can set the JDK location as well as the Android SDK location.

[image: Project Structure Dialog]

Use embedded JDK or else point to your JDK directory. To get your JDK location, run `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` in terminal. Send 1.7 for Java 7 or 1.8 for Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

**1**) Download [**JDK**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

**2**)  **Android Studio** -> **File** -> **Project structure** -> **JDK location**. Point at where you have installed it.

Comment: Use embedded JDK is prefered