# Please Choose a Valid JDK Directory

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make new android project. But I am getting this error "Please Choose a Valid JDK Directory"
I am new to programming can you help me with this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choose a Valid JDK Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845463/choose-a-valid-jdk-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means your Android Studio is can't find where the JDK is installed on your development machine.

To fix this error:

- Select File > Project structure… from the Android Studio toolbar.
- Select SDK Location from the left-hand menu.
- Make sure the "Use embedded JDK checkbox" is selected.

If this doesn’t solve the problem, 
then navigate back to-

**File > Project structure… > SDK Location**, and manually enter the full file path for your JDK.

If you have not downloaded JDK you can also [download](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) JDK;

then in Android Studio ->

> **File -> Project structure -> JDK location**.

Choose location  at where you have installed it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is does not work cause AS don't change the JDK path and says: "Please choose a valid JDK 8 directory"