# Android Studio 3.5.3, change jdk/java version

Tags: java, android-studio

I made sure that i have java 16 on my computer in JAVA_HOME and Path(in CMD: java -version and threw java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20)

In android studio, there is the default java (C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre), that when i run the same CMD command it says is java 8. (This is appart from my problem but i cant use lambdas because is not supported with a language of "7", why is that?)

I tried to change the java version in Android Studio (file/project structure/SDK location/JDK Location), but when i do it (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2) and press apply it says "Please choose a valid JDK 8 directory"

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: 3.5.3, it is in the title

Comment: Welcome  to Stackoverflow. Have you taken a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062636/please-choose-a-valid-jdk-directory

Comment: @Vinnie i already had jdk installed (16) but i downloaded the 17 version(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4.1), and it keeps telling me "Please choose a valid JDK 8 directory". BTW there is no checkbox called "Use embedded JDK" just in case you wanted to know that

Comment: Android Studio 3.5.3 is almost three years old. At the time it was released, Java 13 was the latest version of Java. So perhaps it's not surprising it won't work with Java 16. Is upgrading Android Studio an option?

Comment: @LukeWoodward they changed a lot of things and the tutorials i see to keep learning it are not 3 months from now, so i need a older version, and still, it only lets me use the built in java 8(from the android studio file) not another version