# Please Choose a Valid JDK 11 Directory

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I've just set up Android Studio on a new computer with Ubuntu but when I import the project I get the following message:

```
Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings 
Change JDK location
```

The embedded JDK at `/snap/android-studio/105/android-studio/jre` does not work either, same error message.

Then I've tried java-11 that come with Ubuntu located in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`, but it said `Please Choose a Valid JDK 11 Directory`.

After that not working I've tried to install openjdk `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk` and after setting jdk location to `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11` the same error message appeared.

Neither of those questions helped:

[Choose a Valid JDK Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845463/choose-a-valid-jdk-directory)

[Please Choose a Valid JDK Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062636/please-choose-a-valid-jdk-directory)

Comment: Try setting `JAVA_HOME` environment.

Comment: @Darkman. Thank you. It did solve the issue